# Keep a list with img on a same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how to place different `li` or `div`  with img inside centered on a same line.

Here is a  picture of what I want to have:

[image]

[Here](http://pierredebroux.be/test.html) is what I did so far:

As you see the li are displayed vertically but I want to display the li horizontally.

What I've tried is:
I can do it if I use the position absolute for the li and than display each one at different % from the `left:100%` from the left for the first one, 200% for the second one,...

Is it the only solution? I if want to dynamically change the image via javascript maybe it's more easy to keep a `position:relative`.

and here is the code.

html:

```
<div id="pagegallerie">
   <div id="carre1" class="carre"></div>
   <div id="carre2" class="carre"></div>
   <div class="gallerie">
      <li class="pictures" id="yo1"><img src="img/intro1.jpg" alt="Smiley face"></li>
      <li class="pictures"  id="yo2"><img src="img/intro2.jpg" alt="Smiley face"></li>
      <li class="pictures"  id="yo3"> <img src="img/intro3.jpg" alt="Smiley face"></li>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the css :

```
#pagegallerie {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.gallerie {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 85%;
    top: 7.5%;
    bottom: 7.5%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
li img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
#carre1 {
    left: 2.5%;
    background-image: url("../img/arrowb.png");
}
#carre2 {
    right: 2.5%;
    background-image: url("../img/arrow.png");
}
#carre1:hover, #carre2:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.carre {
    width: 60px;
    height: 76px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -38px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/pierre29177/pen/eNPaOE) I made :

Comment: @Sagar Thanks for the edit.

Comment: you could always do something like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLEoxd

Comment: or this http://jsbin.com/jatabalizo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @RachelGallen thanks for your tries but as you know it's different from what i need. but thanks. http://www.pierredebroux.be/example.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I have found these [Sliders](http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-arrow-navigator-no-jquery.html) for you, in case if you still need help.

You may get a clue for creating your own gallery, it has multiple options like Sliders built with jQuery, Sliders built with out using jQuery, slider with arrow, slider without arrow, etc.., and lot more.

You can use their [library](http://www.jssor.com/development/index.html) or you can make your own library by making changes to their existing library if you are good at JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

[DEMO Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/v4vishnuprasad/v6Lntdk6/2/)

Comment: Hav you check out the fiddle? Is that u need?

Comment: Okk .lemme check through it. Thanks for the reply

Comment: hi i  check it but the images doesn't display.

Comment: @PierreDebroux the images don't display because it's a jsfiddle and the image URLs were unchanged from your question.  Using `display: inline` or (better) `display: inline-block` is probably what you want.

Comment: @VP thanks but i tried with inline but that doesn't force them to stay all on a same line ? i made this codepen with the images    http://codepen.io/pierre29177/pen/eNPaOE